# How to turn json file coordinates in to a coordinates list that python can use

Tags: python, json, coordinates, overpass-api

How to turn this:

```
   dict = {"objects":[
                {
      "type": "node",
      "id": 46049199,
      "lat": 52.2925916,
      "lon": 4.9485062,
      "tags": {
      "traffic_calming": "table"
        }
    },
  {
      "type": "node",
      "id": 46053305,
      "lat": 52.2936706,
       "lon": 4.9469035,
       "tags": {
       "barrier": "gate"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "node",
        "id": 46053351,
       "lat": 52.2934958,
       "lon": 4.9463902
        }
```

into this

```
      coordTD2 = {46049199: [52.2925916, 4.9485062], 46053305: [52.2936706, 4.9469035], 4 
        46053351: [52.2934958, 4.9463902]}
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Where are you stuck? Please provide an [MCVE] to make helping you easier. Your task can be solved by iterating over your data and accessing the relevant data via its dict keys. Do you already know how lists and dicts are working?

Answer (score 2):

Take every dictionary in the `objects` list and pick out the id, lat and lon as follows:

```
dic = {"objects":[
                {
      "type": "node",
      "id": 46049199,
      "lat": 52.2925916,
      "lon": 4.9485062,
      "tags": {
      "traffic_calming": "table"
        }
    },
  {
      "type": "node",
      "id": 46053305,
      "lat": 52.2936706,
       "lon": 4.9469035,
       "tags": {
       "barrier": "gate"
      }
      },
      {
      "type": "node",
        "id": 46053351,
       "lat": 52.2934958,
       "lon": 4.9463902
        },
    ]
}

newdic = {}
for d in dic['objects']:
   newdic[d['id']] = [d['lat'], d['lon']]

print(newdic)
```

Comment: Or as a single line expression: `{item['id']: [item['lat'], item['lon']] for item in d['objects']}`

Comment: You are a lifesaver!

Comment: If this works for you please accept the answer, and if you like it, please upvote it.